# Is there a way to only parse EditTexts that is not empty?

Tags: android

I am creating an app that solves for the missing parts of an oblique triangle if it is solvable but I am having a hard time in parsing the data from EditTexts. Here is a sample of my code:

```
Double A, B, C, a, b, c;
    aa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.angleA);
    ab = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.angleB);
    ac = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.angleC);
    sa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sideA);
    sb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sideB);
    sc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sideC);

if (!aa.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        A = Double.parseDouble(aa.getText().toString());
    }

    if (!ab.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        B = Double.parseDouble(ab.getText().toString());
    }

    if (!ac.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        C = Double.parseDouble(ac.getText().toString());
    }

    if (!sa.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        a = Double.parseDouble(sa.getText().toString());
    }

    if (!sb.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        b = Double.parseDouble(sb.getText().toString());
    }

    if (!sc.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        c = Double.parseDouble(sc.getText().toString());
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a shorter way of coding this.

Comment: Why don't you create one method which will check and parse it

Comment: Shorter? in what? number of lines?

Comment: Okay. Finally got my problem solved. My problem was just, the program crashes when you force a parse on empty edittexts. What I did is I used try and catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest, readable way I can think of:

```
// Store EditText ids in an array
int[] editTextIds = new int[] { R.id.angleA, R.id.angleB,
        R.id.angleC, R.id.sideA, R.id.sideB, R.id.sideC };
// Store EditText values in an ArrayList
ArrayList<Double> results = new ArrayList<>();

// Loop ids, saving values to ArrayList
for (int id : editTextIds) {
    String value = ((EditText) findViewById(id)).getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
        results.add(null);
    } else {
        results.add(Double.valueOf(value));
    }
}

// Now:
// results.get(0) = A
// results.get(1) = B
// results.get(2) = C
// results.get(3) = a
// results.get(4) = b
// results.get(5) = c
// If results.get(x) returns null, means value isn't set
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to do the work:

```
Double A, B, C, a, b, c;

public void calc()
{
    A = getValueOrNan(R.id.angleA);
    B = getValueOrNan(R.id.angleB);
    C = getValueOrNan(R.id.angleC);
    a = getValueOrNan(R.id.sideA);
    b = getValueOrNan(R.id.sideA);
    c = getValueOrNan(R.id.sideA);

    if (A == Double.NaN)
    {
        // calc A
    }
    if (B == Double.NaN)
    {
        // calc B
    }

    // ...
}

public Double getValueOrNan(int id)
{
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(id);

    if (!et.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());
    }
    else
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `A != Double.NaN` it won't check B.

Answer (score 0):

use [TextUtils.isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and Java exception handling

```
aa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.angleA);
ab = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.angleB);
ac = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.angleC);
sa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sideA);
sb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sideB);
sc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sideC);

//Rest of the stuff
//
Double saDouble=getVal(sa);


public Double getVal(EditText et){
Double op=Double.NAN;     
try{
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText()))
   Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
  //log,toast,dialog whatever you need to display.
}
 return op;
}
```